# how to get a value of select item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a problem with this code:

```
$("#btn_agregar").on("click", function(){
        $('#tab > tbody:last-child')
           .append('<tr><td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="'+$("#fecha_cobro")
              .val()+'"></td><td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="'+$("#fech option:selected")
              .val()+'"</td><td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="'+$("#tipo_serv").val()+'"</td></tr>');
    });
```

what I have to do for my select id=fech and select id=tipo_serv get the value of selected item?

Comment: Missing closing bracket for some of the input elements

Comment: this is working properly ... unless your IDs are out of place https://jsfiddle.net/w513pvz1/